# Extra space above keyboard view iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have added code for pushing table view above keyboard. I have change the bottomLayout constraint of table view. But, he i set the constraint, there is an extra space above keyboard.

I have added sample code for keyboard showing notification.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
   CGRect rect = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
   CGRect rectInView = [self.view rect fromView:nil];

   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.bottomLayoutConstraint.constant = rectInView.size.height;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
}
```

After this i got the following output in the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Hey wait a second , tableview automatically adjusts to the keyboard right ? Why are you even doing this ??

Comment: @Sahman: The bottom items in tableview will be behind keyboard.

Comment: Did you find a solution?